# Not updating struct values in map of multimaps

Tags: c++, dictionary, struct, iterator, multimap

I'm using C++ and have a number of data structures that I need to update things in. I use a map from double to multi maps of int and my struct. It looks like this:

```
std::map<double, std::multimap<int, dnode*> *> m_ptable;
```

My struct definition looks like this:

```
struct dnode{
    std::string ticker;
    double buy;
    double sell;

    //(sell/buy)
    double result;
    bool hasDuplicate;
};
```

The issue is that I need to iterate through all of the dnodes in the multi map and update their value of "sell" and "result" because this has to be computed after all of the nodes are already in the multi map. Here is the function I wrote to do that:

```
void dataProcessor::addCloseToEntry(double close){
    map<double, std::multimap<int, dnode*> *>::iterator it;
    multimap<int, dnode*>::iterator mm_it;

    for(it = m_ptable.begin(); it != m_ptable.end(); it++){
        for(mm_it = (it->second)->begin(); mm_it != (it->second)->end(); mm_it++){
            mm_it->second->sell = close;
            mm_it->second->result = close/(mm_it->second->buy);

        }
    }
    return;
}
```

When I step through this code I see that the values for "sell" and "result" are not changing, but remain as 0 (I initialize them to zero when I add a new node into the map.)

Is there something I'm doing incorrectly with the iterators here that's causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know that values are not changing? With some debug output or via debugger?

Comment: @OlegAndriyanov using Xcode debugger and stepping through.

Comment: By the way, the problem in your code is that you use `double` as a key type in `std::map`. Doubles are almost never equal to each other. How is one supposed to find or remove a value from this map? If you add a value in your map with a key of `12.345678`, then to find the added element you'll need to have the exact copy of this key, equal bit by bit. This is very unlikely for floating point values to be totally equal -- the equality is usually considered with some precision like "epsilon". I guess this is the root of your bug.

Comment: @OlegAndriyanov based on my implementation, I don't need to remove and replace the key. I need it there purely as an index.

Comment: @jonnyd42 looks like it works fine here: http://ideone.com/h96Eo7

Comment: @jonnyd42 If you are still intending to find elements in a map, you should choose another key type. If you don't need to search by key, then map is unnecessary at all -- `vector` of structs would be sufficient.

Comment: @OlegAndriyanov I'm storing values in the doubles for the map used in calculations. For my application, it is a good option. My goal isn't to find things based on key, but map was a logical choice because I literally needed to map numbers to multi maps containing more data.

Comment: @Rochet2  It's not working for me :(. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this code works fine. My logic was messed up in the lines before this. This function was called inside a while loop with a parameter that was reinitialized to zero before it was called every time.

Wow.

Thanks anyway guys!